# How do i get the NUnit2XmlResultWriter.dll into my project to use it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, nuget, nunit

I want to write that C# code [convert-nunit-3-nunit-2-results-xml-file](https://automationrhapsody.com/convert-nunit-3-nunit-2-results-xml-file/), but despite the added nuget package i'm missing the dll in my project.
I see it in the tool's directory of the package cache, but missing it in my project.
What do i overlook?

[image]

My project is at present for .Net Core 2.1. Is my issue therefore related to this: [Add support for net standard](https://github.com/nunit/nunit-v2-result-writer/issues/12) ?
I'm new to .net and don't understand all the differences so far.

Comment: Hi Sebastian, I agreed with Charlie's idea and this package have not supported .NET Core yet, please redirect to this: https://github.com/nunit/nunit-v2-result-writer/issues and recommend the author to add this feature, thank you for your understanding.

Comment: As I'm coming from Java, I'm still new to .Net.
@SaraLiu-MSFT
This issue is not enough [Add support for net standard](https://github.com/nunit/nunit-v2-result-writer/issues/12) ? It needs to be Core in addition?
As this package is not intended to be used as library I'm not sure how to include it. Creating my own, local, nuget package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As zivkan explained, the package is a tool. In fact, it's an extension to another tool, the NUnit engine package. The NUnit engine knows how to find and use the extension.

NUnit does **not** publish a package that is intended for use by your code as a library, because we would then have to support it as a library in addition to it's use as an extension to NUnit.

However, NUnit's MIT license allows you to use the source code, which you can find at https://github.com/nunit/nunit-v2-result-writer

Since the code has not yet been ported to .NET Core, you would have to do that yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the details, i hoped for an answer from you. :-)
The reason why i tried this, was our TFS 2017 which not supports the Nunit3 format of xml test results. I hope for an upgrade to 2018 this year.
My actual workaround is to use dotnet test with logger:trx. As a port would be too much work for me, ill stay with that. I hoped for a quick solution.

Comment: While .NET Core support might also be useful, support for .NET Standard is sufficient when the library is called by either user code or as an extension by the .NET Standard build of the NUnit engine.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't overlook anything. Not all NuGet packages are libraries.

NuGet has conventions on how files must be packed in order to use various features. For example, files in the `content` or `contentFiles` get copied into the project directory, or build output, depending if the project using the package uses `packages.config`, or `PackageReference`. If the package author wants to give you a library that you can use in your code, they must put the library in the `lib` directory in the nupkg (technically it could be in `ref`, but those don't get copied to build/publish output, they're only used at build time). The `tools` directory is, unsurprisingly, intended for tools packages. It's often used by unit test runners, or in this case, a report generator.

So, since the package puts the dlls in the `tools` directory, this means the package author intends the package to be a tool to assist you during development, but not as a library for you to use in your code. You could try contacting the package author to see if they have published another package with the same dll, this time in the `lib` directory, so that you can use it your project.

Otherwise you'll need to find a solution that doesn't rely on NuGet bringing you this dll as a library. One option is to have a `packages.config` file that extracts the package in a solution `packages` directory, and then you use a dll reference to the dll. Your build script would then need to first restore the `packages.config` file before building your project. Another option is to check in the dll into your source control management tool, if the dll's license allows that, and again have a dll reference to it.

Comment: Thanks, i feared something like that.